# How to rewrite to an EditText after screen rotation using fragment in android

Tags: android

I know this question have been asked many times here but I tried all the answers with no success.

My `EditText` looses everything I typed after I rotate the screen even though I get the data logged after recreation

I have this code in my fragment

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState);
    saveState.putString("A1", A1.getText().toString());

}

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d("Novinyo2", savedInstanceState.getString("A1"));

        String A1_value = savedInstanceState.getString("A1");
        EditText A1_ = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txta1);
        A1_.setText(A1_value);

    }

    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    text1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.accord1);
    text2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.accord2);
    text3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.accord3);

    Code = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stationcode);
    Name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stationname);

    A1 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txta1);
    A2 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txta2);


    text1.setOnClickListener(this);
    text2.setOnClickListener(this);
    text3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Try setting the text in the onActivityCreated() method.

Comment: It's not working that way too

Comment: Are you sure you don't misspell the id of the EditText? Second, why do you use two variables (A1, A1_) to store the EditText?

Comment: If there was a misspell I don't think I will be able to store it in the saveState  bundle and then retrieve it to be able to put it in the Log.d() of the resotreState after recreation of the fragment. For A1 and A1_ it just because I was only using A1 and since I wasn't getting it right I tried to create another instance to see if that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState);
    saveState.putString("A1", A1.getText().toString());

}
```

you are saving an empty Bundle and then you are putting a value to bundle,
so when you are trying to retrieve those data the bundle is empty.

try that

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveState){
    saveState.putString("A1", A1.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState);
}
```

**UPDATE**

on your Manifest file do you have that attribute     `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on your activity tag?

Comment: on your Manifest file do you have that attribute     `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on your activity tag?

Comment: Thanks it's working now after I added the configChanges to the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState)` after saving your data.

The resulting code:

```
saveState.putString("A1", A1.getText().toString()); 
super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState);
```